# How can I provide a BE response for a directive in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-directives

I want to make a 'lazy-loader' for my gallery. So I want to show a loading .gif image while the image is not loaded in.

I have an array with attributes like filename, type and so on, but there is a back-end request which gives back the image real access url (it is needed to download and open the image at all) and this url will be added for each its element of the array as 'sUrl' property

**... and ...**

then I have an array with image properties, so array[0].sUrl will be pass over to the directive as attr, which directive is on the img html element:

```
<img src="lazyloading.gif" ImageLazyLoading="array[0].sUrl">
<img src="lazyloading.gif" ImageLazyLoading="array[1].sUrl">
<img src="lazyloading.gif" ImageLazyLoading="array[2].sUrl">
```

**In the directive I want to do something like:**

```
@Input() src: string;
@Input() ImageLazyLoading: string;

const fakeImg = new Image();
fakeImg.src = this.ImageLazyLoading;
fakeImg.addEventListener('load', () => {
    src = fakeImg.src;
}, false);
```

But the only problem is that when this directive initializes, array[0].sUrl property does not exist! The reason may be that the BE service is not finished.

I have tried out the all of the lifecycle hooks, it did not help at all. Only ngAfterViewChecked() when may be appropriate for me, but if it is the only way, there is no need for a directive, I can do it in the component.

```
[service]
   |
[parent] -> [child]

parent: where the BE request is (that fn is in a service)
child: where the img and directive are
```

**There is any way to solve this problem using directive?**

Comment: Generate img elements with ngFor and put ngIf on it with checking whether array.length > 0

Comment: It is generated with ngFor. And? I do not understand why it would help on me...